# Was post-exposure perspective correction ever practiced in the darkroom?

Tags: history, darkroom

It seems like it should have been possible to achieve by adding tilt and shift movements to the enlarger lens, projecting a keystoned image of the film on the printing paper and cropping accordingly, but was it ever done ?

Comment: Hi user 35234221, Welcome to Photography. This is still a handy thing to know how to do. It's called the Scheimpflug principle. Scheimpflug was a surveyor by trade.

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with the Scheimpflug principle, just didn't know if it was commonly applied in darkroom printing as well as in camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This perspective correction was done all the time. It's very effective.

BUT,

It can throw off the focus of the image on the easel. Stopping down can help with the focus if the "correction" isn't too severe.

What to do?

Small corrections in the negative holder can be used to tilt it in much the same way as a view camera uses shifts and tilts of the lens board to much the same thing.

Here's more about it with some illustrations from the ["Printer's Attic"](http://printerattic.com/2016/04/method-correcting-perspective-in-the-darkroom/).

Comment: Thanks ! (Also if you're in touch with the owner of that site please bring to his attention that his SSL certificate is broken)

Comment: @user35234221 My mistake in adding the link details. It should be okay by now. Thank you.